# Derivative of Matrix and its transpose with regards to itself

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

How do you calculate this derivative? W does not have any special properties (i.e not square, not symmetric)

$$    \frac{\partial W W^T}{\partial W}$$

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Derivative of a matrix with respect to a matrix yields a 4th order tensor.

Comment: I suspect that you need this derivative as part of a chain rule calculation. In that case, it would be better if you described the underlying problem, as it may be possible to solve it without explicitly calculating this 4th order tensor.

Comment: recently one similar question was [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3451203/683216)